# REST API - One to zero-or-one association

Tags: api, rest

I've tried to find a good way to work with one to zero-or-one association.

I have two resources. The first resource has one to zero-or-one association with the second resource.

(in the example below I will use Page and Line. You can think that a Page can only have "one" or "zero" Line)

At the first moment I thought to retrieve the data by using this approach:

```
/api/pages/:id/
```

When the Page has one Line

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test",
  "line": {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "aaa"
  }
}
```

When the Page hasn't one Line

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test"
}
```

That way when the developer gets a list of pages he doesn't need to make more requests to the API to get the Line of each Page.
But if the page doesn't have one Line, is the best way only to avoid to show the "line" and explain it in the documentation? Or add a boolean named "has_line"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution would be

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test",
  "lines": [{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "aaa"
  }]
}
```

and

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test",
  "lines": []
}
```

But if you are certain there won't be more lines later, then I would stick with your approach. You need to document it no matter which approach you choose. No need to have a hasLine boolean.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes I'm certain there won't be more lines later. So, when the developer gets the data he will check if there is a line, right?

Comment: @Steven Yes, it is their responsibility. You need to document it, so they will know about it.

Comment: That's great. Thank you one more time. Have a good day!